# How to fire a trigger after finishing data insert in a table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle9i

I have a `table A` into which I am inserting data. Then some calculation is being done updating the same `table A`.

I want to fire a trigger, which calls a `Procedure A` after the completion of data insertion ( after insert and update ).

How do I do this?

Is there any other way to do it automatically... Or do I have to run `Procedure A` manualy after the completion of data insertion in `table A`.

---

More simply, I would like to know how to fire a trigger after inserting a few rows and a commit, i.e. not for each row.

Comment: why an after update trigger doesn't help you? (not for each; a statement trigger)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your trigger to be fired for each row or for each statement (FOR EACH ROW option).

If I understood you right, you would like to fire the trigger after a bunch of statements? Don't think you can. Even if you can, I would rather not do it. They scatter your program flow / logic and make it harder to understand later how your software works.

Regards

Comment: i think u are right...i dint find anything on internet also..
will try any other option..anyways thanks...

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the trigger to fire after you completed your transaction consisting of several insert/update statements? If that is the case, I think you should consider calling your `Procedure A` in your program flow right after the insert/update operations are done.

In other words: A trigger would only be useful, if it should be called for each row or for each statement.

Answer (score 0):

Add one column to your table: e.g "FINAL_ACTION". Leave this column untouched untill your anticipated final action. Then have your trigger get fired only with this clause:

```
REFERENCING NEW AS NEWREC OLD AS OLDREC
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEWREC.FINAL_ACTION <> OLDREC.FINAL_ACTION)
DECLARE
     --YOUR DECLARATIONS
BEGIN
     --DO SOMETHING
END;
```